# Numbering Regex Submatches

Tags: regex, tree-traversal, linearization

Is there a canonical ordering of submatch expressions in a regular
expression?

For example: What is the order of the submatches in
"(([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3}))\s+([A-Z]+)" ?

```
a. (([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{3}))\s+([A-Z]+)  
   (([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{3}))  
   ([A-Z]+)  
   ([0-9]{3})  
   ([0-9]{3})  
   ([0-9]{3})  
   ([0-9]{3})  

b. (([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{3}))\s+([A-Z]+)  
   (([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{3}))  
   ([0-9]{3})  
   ([0-9]{3})  
   ([0-9]{3})  
   ([0-9]{3})  
   ([A-Z]+)
```

or

```
c. somthin' else.
```

Answer (score 4):

They tend to be numbered in the order the capturing parens start, left to right. Therefore, option b.

Answer (score 2):

In Perl 5 regular expressions, answer b is correct.  Submatch groupings are stored in order of open-parentheses.

Many other regular expression engines take their cues from Perl, but you would have to look up individual implementations to be sure.  I'd suggest the book [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://books.google.com/books?id=ucwR4KIvExMC&dq=mastering+regular+expressions&pg=PP1&ots=QLvzs24_Ik&sig=wUON6Y-GbGfHClq73nJNbdhQecQ&hl=en&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=1&ct=result) for a deeper understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You count opening parentheses, left to right.  So the order would be

```
(([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3}))
([0-9]{3})
([0-9]{3})
([0-9]{3})
([0-9]{3})
([A-Z]+)
```

At least this is what Perl would do.  Other regex engines might have different rules.